# Rewrite Subdomains in Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, subdomain, rewrite

I know with apache you can rewrite subdomains to folders dynamically, as shown in the following: http://muffinresearch.co.uk/archives/2006/08/20/redirecting-subdomains-to-directories-in-apache/ but is it possible to do such a thing with tomcat?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at http://www.tuckey.org/urlrewrite/
HTP,